# Office .NET COM add-in create child window

Tags: office-interop, mdi

There is plenty of documentation of how to create an application-level add-in for Microsoft Office using .NET and COM interop. Using that technique it's easy to create and display forms either using Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation.

However, these forms are not integrated into the Office application's native [multi-document interface (MDI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) heirarchy. Is there a way to attach a .NET-based form to an Office application as a child window, so that a add-in form can be integrated into the hosting application's user interface as a whole?